# Regex - invalid expression error "Nothing to repeat at..."

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a regex to catch a useful part of my S3 filename uploads. I used a regex generator and so far I have this test (which results in an error thrown on javascript):

```
/[A-Za-z]++[^\.\w][^\.]++|(?<=_)\w++(?=\.)/g
```

Here are some example strings that I am working with (with the require pattern to match):

```
"MTxoZbRRUu9BfQLvAWwP_Bruntwood Leeds Digital Festival ad.pdf" // desired match "Bruntwood Leeds Digital Festival ad"

"bbZRU3329BfXXvvAWwP_short-video.mp4" // desired match "short-video"

"zQZFnWVcRUbFNGyGdIP0_MGI-Artificial-Intelligence-Discussion-slides.pptx" // desired match "MGI-Artificial-Intelligence-Discussion-slides"
```

If it helps - I need to run this regex test on javascript.

```
const filename = "bbZRU3329BfXXvvAWwP_short-video.mp4";
const match = filename.match(regex);
console.log(match); // "short-video"
```

Thank you!

Comment: Possessive quantifier is not supported by JS.

Comment: I don't know what "regex generator" you used, but that's not a good JavaScript regular expression for several reasons.

Comment: `++` is not supported by JS (yet) and `(?<=)` is not supported by most browsers, currently. Make sure you set up your regex generator for JS or ECMAScript.

Comment: I used http://regex.inginf.units.it/ which to be fair to them, did not say was specifically for javascript. I am not experienced at all in regex and so cannot comment on the quality of this expression.

Comment: I would recommend against trying to generate a regex from sample data; just write the code yourself.

Comment: Read their [FAQ](http://regex.inginf.units.it/faq.html): _“The regular expression generated does not work! There are **too many `+`** in it! Are you generating wrong regular expressions? — No, the generated regular expression is syntactically correct. However, in order to work it **requires a regular expression engine which supports possessive quantifiers** like the Java one.”_

Comment: Can filename contain dots like `filename.with.dots.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your examples, you could use a much simpler regex:

```js
const regex = /_([^.]+)/;

const inputs = [
  "MTxoZbRRUu9BfQLvAWwP_Bruntwood Leeds Digital Festival ad.pdf", // desired match "Bruntwood Leeds Digital Festival ad"
  "bbZRU3329BfXXvvAWwP_short-video.mp4", // desired match "short-video"
  "zQZFnWVcRUbFNGyGdIP0_MGI-Artificial-Intelligence-Discussion-slides.pptx" // desired match "MGI-Artificial-Intelligence-Discussion-slides"
];

for (const input of inputs) {
  const match = input.match(regex);
  console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I used a regex generator

But not for JavaScript regexes, it seems. Every tool and library has its own regex quirks. In particular, JS doesn't support possessive quantifiers like `++` (nor independent submatches in general, `(?>` `)`).

JS also does not support look-behind, `(?<=` `)`.

You could e.g. do this instead:

```js
const strs = [
    "MTxoZbRRUu9BfQLvAWwP_Bruntwood Leeds Digital Festival ad.pdf",
    "bbZRU3329BfXXvvAWwP_short-video.mp4",
    "zQZFnWVcRUbFNGyGdIP0_MGI-Artificial-Intelligence-Discussion-slides.pptx",
];

for (const str of strs) {
    const m = /_([^.]+)\./.exec(str);
    if (!m) {
        console.log("no match: " + str);
        continue;
    }
    console.log("match: " + m[1]);
}
```

Comment: [RegExp Lookbehind Assertions](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-RegExp_Lookbehind_Assertions) are not yet supported, though they’re in the final feature set for the upcoming ECMAScript 2018 release.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex generators if they don't provide your end regex flavor as flavors syntax and features may differ from each other. You are basically doing this:

```
_[^.]+
```

with the only one difference that it matches preceding `_` character too that you can work around it later in JS.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/p1Z7WW/1)

```js
var text = `MTxoZbRRUu9BfQLvAWwP_Bruntwood Leeds Digital Festival ad.pdf
bbZRU3329BfXXvvAWwP_short-video.mp4
zQZFnWVcRUbFNGyGdIP0_MGI-Artificial-Intelligence-Discussion-slides`;

console.log(
  text.match(/_[^.]+/g).map(v => v.substr(1))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For these example strings you could split on a dot and an underscore `[._]`

That will give you an array with 3 parts. The values you are looking for are in the second part `[1]`:

```js
const strings = [
  "MTxoZbRRUu9BfQLvAWwP_Bruntwood Leeds Digital Festival ad.pdf",
  "bbZRU3329BfXXvvAWwP_short-video.mp4",
  "zQZFnWVcRUbFNGyGdIP0_MGI-Artificial-Intelligence-Discussion-slides.pptx"
];

strings.forEach((s) => console.log(s.split(/[_.]/)[1]));
```